# Running C program with opemcv in cygwin environment

Tags: c, opencv, cygwin

I am newbie in cygwin. However, I have used mingw so far, but it is not supporting `fork()`, so I need to switch to cygwin.

Does cygwin support opencv and how (reference)?

Comment: DUPLICATE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8278/how-do-i-configure-opencv-and-cygwin-to-work-together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of http://hvrl.ics.keio.ac.jp/kimura/opencv/. I fixed the bug in loading jpeg files. Please check my new patch.

Comment: I just tried your prebuilt package, but webcam support still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed opencv with cygwin, all recent distributions. I found [** THIS LINK **](http://hvrl.ics.keio.ac.jp/kimura/opencv/) very helpful. You're suppose to install first ffmpeg, then to patch opencv 2.4.2 distribution (!!) and, eventually, to install opencv.

To make it work with pkg-config I had to modify ${OPENCV_ROOTDIR}\lib\pkgconfig and to filter windows path syntax to unix path syntax. pkg-config is not mandatory but it simplifies application development (when correctly installed).

After some effort all this works; but if I can open pgn image files I can't open jpeg image files... Still investigating...

Claude